# AttributeError: ' ' object has no attribute 'soup'

Tags: python-3.5, beautifulsoup

When l call the following function

```
def get_words(self):
    blocks = self.soup.find_all("block", {"blockType": lambda x: x not in ('Separator', 'SeparatorsBox')})

    wrds_blcks = []

    for i, block in enumerate(blocks):
        if block['blockType'] == 'Table':
            rslt = self._get_words_from_block_table(block)

        else:
            rslt = self._get_words_from_block_text(block)

        rslt = self._cleanup_word(rslt)
        if rslt != [[]] and rslt != []:
            wrds_blcks.append(rslt)

    return wrds_blcks
```

l get the following error

```
 in get_words
    blocks = self.soup.find_all("block", {"blockType": lambda x: x not in ('Separator', 'SeparatorsBox')})
AttributeError: 'AbbyExtractor' object has no attribute 'soup'
```

referring to the first line :

```
 blocks = self.soup.find_all("block", {"blockType": lambda x: x not in ('Separator', 'SeparatorsBox')})
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `soup` first. Pass the `html` code retrieved from the webpage as an argument to the `get_words` method. And make the `soup`. Then do your tasks.

```
def get_words(self, html):

    self.soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
    blocks = self.soup.find_all("block", {"blockType": lambda x: x not in ('Separator', 'SeparatorsBox')})

    wrds_blcks = []

    for i, block in enumerate(blocks):
        if block['blockType'] == 'Table':
            rslt = self._get_words_from_block_table(block)

        else:
            rslt = self._get_words_from_block_text(block)

        rslt = self._cleanup_word(rslt)
        if rslt != [[]] and rslt != []:
            wrds_blcks.append(rslt)

    return wrds_blcks
```

Comment: @vincent If it's a `xml` file then replace `html.parser` with `lxml`.